# Sonarqube User Wise Report

Tags: gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I have been trying to create a CI CD using GitLab, Jenkins, and sonarqube for the last week. I have a project with multiple people working on it. and the pipeline is working fine. now I have a doubt about sonar scanning. Can we get user-wise scanning results if we create user logins in sonarqube? If possible, how?

Now sonar gives an overall report. one does not need to see others' bugs. That is why I am trying to separate it.